# Что не так с моим кодом Наивного Байеса вариации Гаусиана?

Tags: python, теорема-байеса

Код такой:

```
class GaussianNB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self, X, y):           

        separated = [[x for x, t in zip(X, y) if t == c] for c in np.unique(y)]
        self.model = np.array([np.c_[np.mean(i, axis=0), np.std(i, axis=0)]
                    for i in separated])
        return self

    def _prob(self, x, mean, std):

        exponent = np.exp(- ((x - mean)**2 / (2 * std**2)))
        return (1.0 / ((np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * std) * exponent))


    def predict_log_proba(self, X):

        return [[sum(self._prob(i, *s) for s, i in zip(summaries, x))
                for summaries in self.model] for x in X]

    def predict(self, X):
        return np.argmax(self.predict_log_proba(X), axis=1)

    def score(self, X, y):
        return sum(self.predict(X) == y) / len(y)
```

а результат выдает такой:

```
gnb = GaussianNB()
gnb.fit(X_train.values, y_train)

gnb_predictions = gnb.predict(X_test.values)
gnb_score_train = gnb.score(X_train.values, y_train)
gnb_score_test = gnb.score(X_test.values, y_test)
```

[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
0.215
0.28

То есть очень плохо работает предсказание - хуже, чем случайно. Хотя вроде и правильно все сделал. Где ошибся?

Данные:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  bag_of_word
0   f   f   e   t   n   c   b   p   t   s   k   d   1   f f e t n c b p t s k
1   f   y   g   f   f   c   b   p   e   k   h   p   0   f y g f f c b p e k h
2   f   y   n   t   n   c   b   n   t   s   k   d   1   f y n t n c b n t s k
3   f   f   e   t   n   c   b   w   t   s   k   d   1   f f e t n c b w t s k
4   x   y   g   f   f   c   b   g   e   k   h   p   0   x y g f f c b g e k h
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
245 x   s   w   t   f   c   b   h   t   s   h   g   0   x s w t f c b h t s h
246 f   f   g   f   f   c   b   p   e   k   h   g   0   f f g f f c b p e k h
247 x   s   b   t   f   c   b   p   t   s   h   g   0   x s b t f c b p t s h
248 f   y   g   f   f   c   b   h   e   k   h   d   0   f y g f f c b h e k h
249 x   y   g   f   f   c   b   p   e   k   h   d   0   x y g f f c b p e k h
250 rows × 14 columns
```

Comment: То есть предсказываются все единицы? Интересно было бы хоть данные посмотреть.

Comment: Добавил в описание данные